# Add offset to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a small script to slide between waypoints on my website:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Now I've got to add an offset. If the users clicks on `<a href="#jumper">JUMP!</a>`

The javascript should scroll to the `<div id="#jumper"></div>` with an offset of 500px. I didn't figure out the right code-section.

Comment: What do you mean by *offset* in this context ?

Comment: Scroll to the #jumper and have got some space to the top (offset)

Comment: Is your current code working ? If yes then just modify (+/-) value of `target.offset().top`

Comment: Yes, it's working very well! Do you mean something like `target.offset(+100).top`?

Comment: **NO**, Something like `parseInt(target.offset().top)+100+'px'`

Comment: Thank you, Raynon. Works fine! So simple...

Answer (score 0):

```
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset(+500).top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
```

.offset(+500)  <-- 500px